# maven-release plugin fails to create a release if parent pom uses ranges

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I have a single module project, which I can create releases using [maven-release-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html)

```
16:13:52  [INFO] Run maven with 'release:prepare release:perform -B -U -e -Dresume=false'
...
16:13:56  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
16:13:56  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) @ my-srv ---
16:13:57  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.ScmCheckModificationsPhase - Verifying that there are no local modifications...
16:13:57  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.ScmCheckModificationsPhase -   ignoring changes on: **\pom.xml.next, **\release.properties, **\pom.xml.branch, **\pom.xml.tag, **\pom.xml.backup, **\pom.xml.releaseBackup
16:13:57  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.scm.manager.plexus.DefaultScmManager - Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --show-prefix"
16:13:57  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.scm.manager.plexus.DefaultScmManager - Working directory: d:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\my-srv_master
16:13:57  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.scm.manager.plexus.DefaultScmManager - Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status --porcelain ."
16:13:57  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.scm.manager.plexus.DefaultScmManager - Working directory: d:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\my-srv_master
16:13:57  [Thread-4] WARNING org.apache.maven.scm.manager.plexus.DefaultScmManager - Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? effective-pom.xml
16:13:57  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.CheckDependencySnapshotsPhase - Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
16:13:57  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RewritePomsForReleasePhase - Transforming 'WS-Proxy'...
16:13:57  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.GenerateReleasePomsPhase - Not generating release POMs
16:13:57  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RunPrepareGoalsPhase - Executing goals 'clean verify'...
16:13:59  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] Scanning for projects...
16:13:59  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] 
16:13:59  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] --------------< com.mycompany.services:my-srv >---------------
16:13:59  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] Building WS-Proxy 1.8.13
16:13:59  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
16:14:00  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] 
16:14:00  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ my-srv ---
16:14:00  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] Deleting D:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\my-srv_master\target
16:14:00  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] 
16:14:00  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (create-buildnumber) @ my-srv ---
16:14:00  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] Change the default 'git' provider implementation to 'jgit'.
16:14:01  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] Storing buildNumber: 31a2d2bb9470473ed8cb36d0493377ad6e8a5103 at timestamp: 1623680040903
16:14:01  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: master
16:14:01  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] 
16:14:01  [Thread-6] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create-timestamp (create-timestamp) @ my-srv ---
...
```

I use a fixed version for the parent pom

```
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.services</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>my-srv</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.8.14-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
```

No we actually want to use version ranges for the parent

```
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.services</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>[0.5.0,0.7.0)</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>my-srv</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.8.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
```

However, this now fails as follows

```
10:58:54  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
10:58:54  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) @ my-srv ---
10:58:54  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.ScmCheckModificationsPhase - Verifying that there are no local modifications...
10:58:54  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.ScmCheckModificationsPhase -   ignoring changes on: **\pom.xml.next, **\release.properties, **\pom.xml.branch, **\pom.xml.tag, **\pom.xml.backup, **\pom.xml.releaseBackup
10:58:54  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.scm.manager.plexus.DefaultScmManager - Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --show-prefix"
10:58:54  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.scm.manager.plexus.DefaultScmManager - Working directory: d:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\my-srv_master
10:58:55  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.scm.manager.plexus.DefaultScmManager - Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status --porcelain ."
10:58:55  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.scm.manager.plexus.DefaultScmManager - Working directory: d:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\my-srv_master
10:58:55  [Thread-4] WARNING org.apache.maven.scm.manager.plexus.DefaultScmManager - Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? effective-pom.xml
10:58:55  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.CheckDependencySnapshotsPhase - Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
10:58:55  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:58:55  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - BUILD FAILURE
10:58:55  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:58:55  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Total time: 2.863 s
10:58:55  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Finished at: 2021-06-21T10:58:55+02:00
10:58:55  [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:58:55  [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project my-srv: Can't release project due to non released dependencies :
10:58:55  [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli -     com.mycompany.services:parent:pom:0.6.1-SNAPSHOT
10:58:55  [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - in project 'WS-Proxy' (com.mycompany.services:my-srv:pom:1.8.12-SNAPSHOT)
10:58:55  [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - -> [Help 1]
10:58:55  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project my-srv: Can't release project due to non released dependencies :
10:58:55      com.mycompany.services:parent:pom:0.6.1-SNAPSHOT
10:58:55  in project 'WS-Proxy' (com.mycompany.services:my-srv:pom:1.8.12-SNAPSHOT)
```

I understand that the dependency `com.mycompany.services:parent:pom:0.6.1-SNAPSHOT` is a `SNAPSHOT` but why. According to [Dependency Mediation and Conflict Resolution](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution#DependencyMediationandConflictResolution-DependencyVersionRanges)

> Resolution of dependency ranges should not resolve to a snapshot (development version) unless it is included as an explicit boundary.

I addition, there is a release version `com.mycompany.services:parent:pom:0.6.1` available.

Comment: Maven version ranges fell out of fashion long time ago. Don't expect them to work properly.

Comment: Yeah I know, I also know it's actually recommended to use fixed versions to have reproducible builds. Still maybe somebody has an idea on how to make this works...

Comment: The problem is not the version range of a dependency it's the part that the dependency is a SNAPSHOT version....

Comment: But why? Release `com.mycompany.services:parent:pom:0.6.1` is present, so should it not take the release version? or how can I ensure it only grabs release versions of dependencies?

Comment: Than your call during the release should be `mvn -U...` because otherwise the local cached version is taken into account instead the one which is remote...finally to make it sure use fixed version instead of ranges...that's the easiest and simplest solution....